# string splitting with multiple values using re.split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, python-re

I have a string:
`"2y20w2d2h2m2s"`
I need to split it to be like that:
`["2y","20w","2d","2h","2m"2s”]`
I tried to use re.split but i couldnt make it work
this was my attempt:
`time = re.split("s m h d w y", time)`
*time is the string above
finally, I will apricate of you would help understand how to make it work

Comment: Do the sections you want the string to split into always start with a 2?

Comment: a good Q that i forgot to sepcify but its not supposed to be only 2 its supposed to be any number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import re

time_str = "2y20w2d2h2m2s"
time = re.findall(r"(\d*\S)", time_str)
print(time)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
['2y', '20w', '2d', '2h', '2m', '2s']
```

**Try it online:**

- https://regex101.com/r/LInbYe/1

Answer (score 0):

In case the sections you want the string to split into always start with `2`, this does the trick:

```
string = "2y20w2d2h2m2s"

print(string.replace('2', ' 2').split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

print(re.findall('(\d+[a-z])', "2y20w2d2h2m2s"))
```

**Output**

```
['2y', '20w', '2d', '2h', '2m', '2s']
```

**Explanation**

Regex pattern for  1 or more numbers followed by a letter

```
(\d+[a-z])
```

Answer (score 0):

Being as specific as possible for your use case:

```
import re
s = "2y20w2d2h2m2s"
re.findall('([0-9]{1,2}[ywdhms]{1})', s)
```

Output: `['2y', '20w', '2d', '2h', '2m', '2s']`

This produces exactly what you want with no extraneous letters or numbers with more than two digits.